# onProgress() event not getting fired for dx-file-uploader

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am trying to get devextreme file uploader to display the progress bar while an attachment is getting uploaded. The documentation shows that there is an onProgress event for the same purpose but if I try using it, it doesn't fire the event (All other events get fired correctly). Also, there is a configuration for progress that gets the current progress in percentages but I am not sure how to use it. Following is an example snippet of what I am trying to do for reference.

```
<dx-file-uploader
    (onValueChanged)='onSelect($event)'
    (onUploaded)='onSuccess($event)'
    (onUploadError)='onError($event)'
    [multiple]='true'
    (onProgress)='onFileProgress($event)'
    progress='percentProgress'
    [labelText]='xyz'>
</dx-file-uploader>
```

Typescript:

```
public onFileProgress(e: { request?: XMLHttpRequest }): void {
   this.percentProgress = 50;
   console.log(this.percentProgress);
}
```

Comment: Did you try with a heavy file? Sometimes, small files do not get an event

Comment: I tried with a 45MB file.. still no luck